# already present: com.google.android.material.internal.package-info

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.material.internal.package-info Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.material.internal.package-info, sources=[Unknown
>   source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

my Gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.videostatus"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.3.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Project Gradle is

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: i am having same issue did you figure out how to remove duplicate?